# Pell's equation easy bound for the fundamental solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

Let $d>1$ be a non-square integer and consider $x^2 - dy^2 = 1$, with minimal solution $(x_0, y_0)$. Can anyone give an explicit bound for $x_0$ (or $y_0$ or $x_0 + y_0\sqrt{d})$ in terms of $d$, but without a complicated proof? I am aware of bounds like $x_0 + y_0\sqrt{d} < d^{c\sqrt{d}}$ for some constant $c$ but all these have complicated proofs. Any explicit bound is fine, no matter how bad it is.

Any help appreciated!